# On Div Hide, Show Twitter Button not displaying properly in Firefox Why?

Tags: jquery, html, twitter, social-media

Hello Everyone from last many days i m trying to display twitter button on share icon hover time. and its working perfect in all browser but getting problem in Firefox browsers.

This is Working

```
<span>
<iframe
  src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets/tweet_button.html?size=l&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdev.twitter.com%2Fweb%2Ftweet-button&via=twitterdev&related=twitterapi%2Ctwitter&text=custom%20share%20text&hashtags=example%2Cdemo"
  width="140"
  height="28"
  title="Twitter Tweet Button"
  style="border: 0; overflow: hidden;">
</iframe>
</span>
```

The above code is worked perfectly but i don't want like as above.. 
i want like there is one share image and if hover on that image than want to show above class so for that i m doing like this

```
<span style="display:none;">
 <iframe
  src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets/tweet_button.html?size=l&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdev.twitter.com%2Fweb%2Ftweet-button&via=twitterdev&related=twitterapi%2Ctwitter&text=custom%20share%20text&hashtags=example%2Cdemo"
  width="140"
  height="28"
  title="Twitter Tweet Button"
  style="border: 0; overflow: hidden;">
</iframe>
</span>
```

i have many post in one page and in that on some post its showing and in some not showing.. the problem is only on Firefox...

PLs HELP me on this..

i have post like

```
Post1
-----
<span>Share image   

Post2
-----
Share Image
<span>
```

like this i have in single page...

problem is only in Firefox and one more things other all social media icons is showing perfectly but only problem for twitter but only in Firefox getting this issue..don't know why this happens

Demo : [http://jsfiddle.net/287dkqm0/2/[1](http://jsfiddle.net/287dkqm0/2/)

open above jsfiddle link in firefox browser in that on hover of Share text twitter button not displaying while on crome its working perfect.. so that's the issue in Firefox...

Comment: why don't you post your full code, like you are showing twitter button with css of js? post your code in http://jsfiddle.net/ will help to understand the problem.

Comment: Thanks.. Lets i added my demo http://jsfiddle.net/287dkqm0/2/

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug as the `display:none` prevents the twitter button from loading in Firefox. There is a workaround: use `opacity:0` instead of `display:none`.

Answer (score 0):

Even I was facing the same issue, but I hacked the solution you can find it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41447355/twitter-share-button-widget-not-working-with-jquery-fadeout-function-in-firefo/41447686) but the actual problem is different and its related to twitter widget I hope this [link](https://twittercommunity.com/t/timeline-widget-vanishes-with-jquery-hide-show/30908) helps you